# Proper 'reactive' way to transform an observable with occasional extra values thrown in

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to apply a transformation to an observable, but I want certain records to produce an additional record in the output.  Here's a procedural version of what I mean:

```
foreach (var source in sourceList)
{
  var destObject = new DestObject(source);
  output.Add(destObject);
  if (source.Type == 7)
  {
    var additionalObject = new DestObject {
      Field1 = xx,
      Field2 = yy,
    };
    output.Add(additionalObject);

  }
}
```

Is there a good functional 'reactive' way to do this?  The best I can come up with is to use SelectMany and then basically use that example function above to create either a 1 or 2 member list and then return that list within the lambda.  That seems OK, but I'm new enough to reactive extensions and functional programming in general that I just don't know if I'm missing a more elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a transform that generates 1 or 2 elements as an `IEnumerable<int>` depending on input. You could return a list but using yield is convienient.

```
IEnumerable<int> Transform(int data){
    if(data == 0){
        yield 1;
    }
    if(data == 1){
        yield 3;
        yield 4;
    }
}
```

Get your source from somewhere

```
IObservable<int> source = ...;
```

Transform your source data using SelectMany

```
IObservable<int> sink = source.SelectMany(Transform);
```

Dump the data to console

```
sink.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

If source gave data

```
0 0 1 1 0
```

then sink would get

```
1 1 3 4 3 4 1
```

Comment: I never think to use yield.  It seems the most readable way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

> The best I can come up with is to use SelectMany and then basically use that example function above to create either a 1 or 2 member list and then return that list within the lambda

Seems reasonable to me:

```
sourceList.ToObservable()
    .SelectMany(x => Observable.Return(x)
        .Concat(x.Type == 7 ? Observable.Return(newThing) : Observable.Empty(x));
```

Comment: The concat is not an option I had thought of